# Docker volumes must be unique error when i try and build docker-compose with two containers

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and i am trying to spin up docker with 2 containers. 1 container contains the the sqlserver and the other contains a dotnet core web api. When i run docker-compose i am getting an error about volumes which i don't understand. I am getting that error on a pc. When i run the exact same project on a mac, its just building and never finishes, but i dont get an error

Here is my docker.compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  dockerapi:

services:
  demoappdb:
    container_name: db-container
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019/latest
    ports:
      - 8002:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
    networks:
      - dockerapi
    
  dockerapi:
    container_name: api-container
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerAPI/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    depends_on:
      - demoappdb
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=demoappdb
      - DB_NAME=DemoAppDB
      - DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx
    networks:
      - dockerapi
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["dockerAPI/dockerAPI.csproj", "dockerAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./dockerAPI/./dockerAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/dockerAPI"
RUN dotnet build "./dockerAPI.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./dockerAPI.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dockerAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: That's weird since you don't seem to be using any volumes. Can you try doing `docker compose build dockerapi` to see if the dockerapi can build OK? If it can build then it must be a problem when running the container.